# Generacion ventana en JS

Tags: javascript, html

tengo el siguiente codigo js cuando ejecuto la funcion "escribe()" con un evento de boton, me sale el siguiente error "Cannot read property 'closed' of undefined" en el if de la funcion, me pueden ayudar?

```
var nuevaventana;

function crearnuevaventana()
{
    var nuevaventana = window.open("", "nueva ventana", "status, heigth=200 width=300");
}

function escribe()
{

    if (nuevaventana.closed)
    {
        crearnuevaventana();
    }

    nuevaventana.focus();
    var contenido = "<html><head><title>Nueva Ventana</title></head>";

    contenido += "<body bgcolor='coral'> <h1>Hola mundo</h1>";
    contenido += "</body> </html>";

    nuevaventana.document.write(contenido);
    nuevaventana.document.closed;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Eso pasa porque dentro de la función **crearnuevaventana()** no usas la variable global **nuevaventana**, sino que defines otra variable con el mismo nombre dentro del scope de la función.

Para solucionarlo debes eliminar el "**var**" dentro de crearnuevaventana().

```
function crearnuevaventana()
{
    nuevaventana = window.open("", "nueva ventana", "status, heigth=200 width=300");
}
```

De esta forma **crearnuevaventana()** inicializa la variable **nuevaventana**.

Answer (score 0):

Sumándome a lo que dice RockoDev, efectivamente estás declarando una variable de ámbito local (existe sólo dentro de `crearnuevaventana`) que no toca la variable de ámbito global.

```
var nuevaventana; // ámbito global: undefined

function crearnuevaventana()
{
    var nuevaventana = window.open(...); // ámbito local
}

crearnuevaventana();

console.log(nuevaventana); // undefined;
```

El primer paso, entonces, sería hacer que tu función escribiera en la variable global:

```
function crearnuevaventana()
{
    nuevaventana = window.open(...); // pisa la variable global
}
```

**Peeero** hay otro problema. Cuando declaras la variable global:

```
 var nuevaventana;
```

ésta tiene valor `undefined`. Existe, pero no tiene valor. El primitivo `undefined` no tiene tal cosa como un atributo `closed`. Cuando quieres comprobar si la ventana está cerrada, y nunca has llamado a `crearnuevaventana`, igual te saldrá ese error.

Lo que puedes hacer, entonces, es inicializarla como un objeto plano con una propiedad `closed`

```
var nuevaventana = { closed: true };
```

Y de esa manera la primera vez que la consultes, efectivamente figurará como cerrada. En los llamados sucesivos, ya habrá sido sobreescrita como un elemento DOM.